# Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

I have a problem with a entity class. When I run my app with hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create, then it create all the other entity tables but not this on. Why is that? And when I create the table by myself and after that try to insert something into it, then I get this error: http://pastebin.com/m4gjxqNC

Here's my entity class:
User entity:
http://pastebin.com/YXvzFSgt
Comment entity:
http://pastebin.com/RpZEUPxN

And here's the UserDAO class
http://pastebin.com/LrTCg0GC

Comment: What DBMS are you using and what JDBC driver? The BBM2DLL might be generating incorrect SQL syntax if you are not using the correct driver for your DB. Also, is Hibernate aware of your User entity? Make sure it is being included in the mapped classes or annotated classes/packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to be using PostgreSQL. As per this [document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), 'User' is a PostgreSQL reserved word. Try adding a @Table("user_tb") annotation for your User entity, to force a new table name.

```
@Entity
@Table("user_tb")
public class User extends LightEntity implements Serializable {
 //..

}
```